# Special characters Android TextView

Tags: java, android

I have a String in text file like this with a special characters

```
Rio Ave;AcadŽmica;0;0;2014-03-07 21:00:00;Est‡dio do Rio Ave Futebol Clube;Liga Portuguesa;""
```

When I setText in Android TextView how can I convert this special characters to see Académica in spite of AcadŽmica. Thank you so much

Comment: Save the text file in UTF8 encoding or load it with whatever encoding it is in.

Comment: Is there a function to write file in UTF8 with filewriter? thanks

Comment: not with `FileWriter` but with `OutputStreamWriter` (`FileWriter` does nothing other than `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file))`) e.g. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-utf-8-encoded-data-into-a-file-java/ - the same applies to reading via `InputStreamReader`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**`UTF-8`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) charset encode in java to display the special characters

```
 String str = "Rio Ave;AcadŽmica;0;0;2014-03-07 21:00:00;Est‡dio do Rio Ave Futebol Clube;Liga Portuguesa";
      byte spbyte[] = str.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
      str = new String( spbyte,"UTF-8");
      textview.setText(str);
```